# strip DOM elements in Puppeteer, without using CSS selectors?

Tags: javascript, xpath, css-selectors, puppeteer

I want to strip some elements and comments from the DOM within Puppeteer.  These items do not have identifiable IDs, classes, or attributes which I can select using CSS.  However, they may be identified by internal strings, and some elements may be wrapped in human-readable comments.  My attempts so far:

- Using CSS selectors does not seem possible, since they only work with an ID or class: [there is no CSS
  `contains()` selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4561376/652626).  So I tried to do it with XPath...
- Some elements may be selected (and potentially removed?) using XPath, but I'm a rookie with both Puppeteer and XPath.  I have provided my aborted attempt below.
- I might instead use a regular expression, but I don't know how to remove strings from the DOM after its HTML has been parsed.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

---

So, in the following example, I would like to delete the elements between the `<!-- DELETE ME ... -->` comments, as well as the `<!-- DELETE ME ... -->` comments at the end:

```
    <html>
      <head>

        <!-- DELETE ME BEGIN -->
        <script>
          // delete me
          console.log('delete me')
        </script>
        <!-- DELETE ME END -->

        <title>Page Title</title>
      </head>

      <body>
        
        <!-- DELETE ME BEGIN -->
        <style>
          body {
            /* delete me */
            color: red;
          }
        </style>
        <script>
          // delete me
          console.log('delete me')
        </script>
        <!-- DELETE ME END-->

        <style>
          body {
            /* keep me  */
            color: green;
          }
        </style>

        <script>
          // keep me
          console.log("keep me")
        </script>
        <p>Keep me</p>
        <!-- keep me -->

      </body>
    </html>

    <!-- DELETE ME -->
    <!-- DELETE ME TOO -->
```

Puppeteer/XPath code (just an attempt, does not yet do anything):

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.on("console", (log) => console[log._type](log._text));

    const html = await page.evaluate(() => {
      var evaluator = new XPathEvaluator();
      var result = evaluator.evaluate(
        "//script[contains(.,'delete me')]",
        document,
        null,
        XPathResult.ANY_TYPE
      );

      console.log(result);

      return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    });

    await browser.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `xpath` looks correct. Puppeteer provides [page
.$x
(expression)](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-pagexexpression) functions to run the `xpath`:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://storm-bald-meteorology.glitch.me');

let xs = await page.$x("//script[contains(. ,'delete me')]");
console.log(xs.length);
for (let x of xs) {
  let txt = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText, x);
  console.log(txt);
}

await browser.close();
```

You can copy/paste this code into [puppeteer playground](https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/) to try it. I have also put your `html` on [glitch](https://storm-bald-meteorology.glitch.me).

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @sam-r !  Your code is better than mine.  Do you also happen to know how I might delete the DOM elements?

Comment: @aljabear, Just call `el.remove()` instead of `el.innerText`.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Note for future self, here is the full code I wrote incorporating @sam-r solution, in this case stripping elements added to rendered [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20020120142510/http://example.com/) entry:

```
   // remove elements by XPath
    [
      ...await page.$x("//script[contains(.,'__wm')]"),
      ...await page.$x("//script[contains(.,'archive.org')]"),
      ...await page.$x("//style[contains(.,'margin-top:0 !important;\n  padding-top:0 !important;\n  /*min-width:800px !important;*/')]"),
      ...await page.$x("//comment()[contains(.,'WAYBACK')]"),
      ...await page.$x("//comment()[contains(.,'Wayback')]"),
      ...await page.$x("//comment()[contains(.,'playback timings (ms)')]"),
    ].forEach(async xpath => await page.evaluate(el => el.remove(), xpath));

    // remove elements by CSS Selector
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
      [
        document.querySelector('link[href*="/_static/css/banner-styles.css"]'),
        document.querySelector('link[href*="/_static/css/iconochive.css"]'),
        ...document.querySelectorAll("#wm-ipp-base"), // wayback header
        ...document.querySelectorAll('script[src*="wombat.js"]'),
        ...document.querySelectorAll('script[src*="archive.org"]'),
        ...document.querySelectorAll('script[src*="playback.bundle.js"]'),
        ...document.querySelectorAll("#donato"), // wayback donation header
      ].forEach((element) => element.remove());
    });
```